# Flutter audio slider with assets_audio_player ,

Tags: flutter

Flutter audio slider with assets_audio_player

I'm trying to create a slider to watch the audio progress and seek some parts of the audio. In order to play local audio files I'm using the assets_audio_player package. This is my code:

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, position and duration are both Duration() variables

```
Widget slider() {
  return Slider(
      value: _position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
      min: 0.0,
      max: _duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
      onChanged: (double value) {
        setState(() {
          seekToSecond(value.toInt());
          value = value;
        });});
}
```